# Упростить вид множества, которое задано с помощью операций

Tags: дискретная-математика

Упростить вид множества, которое задано с помощью операций, применяя законы алгебры множеств (в ответ множества могут входить не более одного раза):[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какой результат ожидается для приведенного примера?

Comment: исправил задание

Comment: а это вообще возможно? Я что-то не придумаю как записать используя множество только 1 раз симметрическую разность.

Comment: вроде как возможно,только я не знаю как

Comment: @pavel, это 1 получается. Или в случае множеств - всё множестно.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не про эту конкретную задачу, я просто задумался, а всегда ли возможно привести формулу к такому виду.

Comment: @pavel, думаю, что не всегда.

Comment: @pavel, вроде, A xor B нельзя записать используя множества не более одного раза, если нам доступны только пересечение, объединение и отрицание.

Answer (score -5):

В случае булевой логики:

```
!(A&B&C) | (A&B) | !C = !A | !B | !C | A&B | !C = !(A&B) | A&B | !C = 1
```

В случаё множёств аналогично получается всё.

Comment: Модератор вместо того, чтобы удалить вопрос (одна из причин тревоги, а значит нарушение правил сайта - `Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.`) отвечает на него, серьезно?

Comment: @Pekor, эта причина - мусор. Закрывать что либо с ней я не стану и не обязан.

Comment: @Pekor в целом, модератор не занимается удалением вопросов/ответов, если это не что-то типа спама, оскорблений и т.д. Он может одним голосом закрыть вопрос, но вообще спорно, должен ли модератор такой мелочевкой заниматься - это должно регулироваться сообществом.

Comment: @Qwertiy поможешь с заданием которое выложил?

Comment: @wwwww2, нееееа.

Comment: @Qwertiy :(((((а если пожалуйстааа